# DART: ISSUE A value of type 'num' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'

Tags: flutter, dart, issuu

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdvyJ.png)

I want to calculate the sum of the given values but i recieve this error

Answer (score 1):

Change `var` to `int`

```
for (int value in values) {
  sum += value;
}
```

and change

```
values = ['1, 3, 5, 7, 9']
```

to

```
values = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```